# Are specific question of chess games useful to our community?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

Seeing that this is a site for strategic games, [many people might ask these types of question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/24/what-is-the-best-move-from-here-on): [What kind of direction should I take here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/21/what-is-the-best-way-to-free-your-queen-as-soon-as-possible), [what kind of move should I make in this situation](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/8/with-the-king-as-last-piece-how-can-you-get-a-draw), [etc](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/9/opening-with-knight)? My question is, Should we allow these kind of question to be asked on our website? Do these questions repel professionals? What are the pros and cons?

Answer (score 7):

If the position is sufficiently interesting, I think that it's a fine question.  A position where one side is clearly lost isn't really interesting.

Tactics questions would be more interesting (i.e. white to move and win) if the answer to the problem wasn't two inches below the puzzle.  Maybe hiding the solution is an option?

Anything along the lines of "What is the correct strategy?" or "What are some of the abstract plans for [color]?" or "What is the evaluation of this endgame?" seem fine IMHO.